# Having trouble updating postgressdb using update clause

Tags: php, sql

I'm having trouble updating my postgressdb using update clause where itemid = "$_get['itemid'];

here's my sql code but it returns **Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR:**

```
$sql="UPDATE tbl_item SET itemname='".$_POST['ItemName']."', highqntythreshold='".$_POST['HQThreshold']."', lowqntythreshold='".$_POST['LQThreshold']."', qntyperunit='".$_POST['QPUnit']."', itemtype='".$_POST['IT']."', description='".$_POST['Description']."', WHERE itemid='". $_GET['itemid'] . "';";
$iteminfo = pg_query($sql);
```

and it also returns "**Warning: pg_affected_rows()** expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in D:\Wamp\wamp\www\Php\CTea\UpdateItem.php on line 303"

```
    if(pg_affected_rows($iteminfo)==1)
{
$msg = "Successfully added new Item, ".ucfirst($_POST['ItemName'])."!";         
}
else
{
$msg = "Error: in saving Item data!...";
}
```

i think i messed up something but can't figure it out where and what i messed up.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. You should read on [how to prevent them in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/53114).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is (at least) in this part:

```
$_POST['Description']."', WHERE itemid='". $_GET['itemid'] . "'
```

There is a comma before the `where`, so you want:

```
$_POST['Description']."' WHERE itemid='". $_GET['itemid'] . "'
```

In general, though, you should just print out the query string after variable substitution.  About 98% of the time, the error is obvious and you can fix it quickly.